# jquery: how to set a click action on a particular column of the table?

Tags: jquery, click, html-table

I have a jquery code, which performs the function when any entry of the table is clicked. 
I want this code to run when a **particular column's entries** are clicked. The code is below:

```
$('td').click(function() {

                var emp = $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
                var url = "timesheet.jsp?ename=" + emp;
                $(location).attr('href', url);

            });
```

Comment: what is 'particular columns entries'? You can assign a class to your particular column's entries and bind event to it.

Comment: this function work's on every entry inside the html table.
I want it to work on a specific column.
for example, if my html table has c1 c2 and c3 as columns, I want my function to work on c3's rows only.

Comment: look at the [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.. so like `$('td:nth-child(3)').click(function() {});` for the 3rd column

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla that would mean that each `td` in the column needs the same `id` which isn't possible/correct in HTML, perhaps you could recommend `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('tr td:eq(0)').click(function() {`

Using the `:eq(index)` selector lets you choose the `td` occuring at a particular index within a `tr`

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

For dynamically added rows you could use the delegated events methodology - make sure to target specific tables if you have more than on on the page.

`$(document).on('click', 'tr td:eq(0)', function(){`

Answer (score 1):

Just want to conclude 
    $('tr td:eq(0)').click(function() {
Using the :eq(index) selector only listen the nth column  in first row,
As ArunPJohny's answer works much better, 
using ':nth-child' selector
    $('td:nth-child(3)').click(function() {}) 
will listen every third column on every row. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery `.index()` http://api.jquery.com/index/

Here is some sample http://jsfiddle.net/9r7Ak/

---

Note: `index` starts from `0`